# Error: java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text is not class Myclass

Tags: java, hadoop, elastic-map-reduce

I have my mapper and reducers as follows. But I am getting some kind of strange exception.
I can't figure out why is it throwing such kind of exception.

```
public static class MyMapper implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Info> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
        OutputCollector<Text, Info> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {
        Text text = new Text("someText")
            //process 
        output.collect(text, infoObjeject);
    }

}

public static class MyReducer implements Reducer<Text, Info, Text, Text> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Info> values,
        OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {
        String value = "xyz" //derived in some way
        //process
        output.collect(key, new Text(value)); //exception occurs at this line
    }

}

System.out.println("Starting v14 ");
JobConf conf = new JobConf(RouteBuilderJob.class);
conf.setJobName("xyz");

String jarLocation =ClassUtil.findContainingJar(getClass());

System.out.println("path of jar file = " + jarLocation);

conf.setJarByClass(RouteBuilderJob.class);

conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Info.class);

conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

//am i missing something here???

conf.setMapperClass(RouteBuilderJob.RouteMapper.class);
conf.setCombinerClass(RouteBuilderJob.RouteReducer.class);
conf.setReducerClass(RouteBuilderJob.RouteReducer.class);


conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

JobClient.runJob(conf);
```

I am getting an exception:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text is not class com.xyz.mypackage.Info
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Writer.append(IFile.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$CombineOutputCollector.collect(Task.java:1307)
at com.xyz.mypackage.job.MyJob$RouteReducer.reduce(MyJob.java:156)
at com.xyz.mypackage.job.MyJob$RouteReducer.reduce(MyJob.java:1)
```

Internally info object (which implements `Writable`) is serialized using `Text`

```
@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String searlizedStr = gson.toJson(this);
    Text.writeString(out, searlizedStr);
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    String s = Text.readString(in);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(s));
    jsonReader.setLenient(true);

Info info = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Info.class);
    //set fields using this.somefield = info.getsomefield() 
}
```

Comment: what is "value" here . I dont find any declaration or anything for "value" variable ? "output.collect(key, new Text(value));" in this line

Comment: @Backtrack value is a string

Comment: @Backtrack can you help me with this?i have spent lot of time  debuging this

Comment: Ya sure .. Im looking into this

Comment: @Backtrack Thanks for the help. Am here only,let me know if u need any need inputs from my side

Comment: Text value = new Text("xyz");   try this one and let me know . Change the type from string to TEXT

Comment: My K2,V2 of reducer is of type Text.Also i have set outputkeyClass an outputvalueclass to text.So why is it complaing like this?Is setting combiner compulsary?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46144/discussion-between-user93796-and-backtrack)

Comment: No . Combiner is not needed .. Yes i have looked the code it  is fine . Just take a try 1. Change the VALUE type to TEXT and 2. remove the Combiner if you dont need it

Comment: Problem solved after the combiner was removed. @Backtrack thanks backtrack

Answer (score 7):

Technically the output types of your reduce should be the same as your input type. This must be true if you use a combiner as the output of the combiner is fed into your reducer.

Comment: Helped me too. But any specific reason why would reducer want both types to remain same