# reduce() can only accept reduce (Text, Text)?

Tags: text, mapreduce

I'm new to MapReduce. Here is my question.

In hdfs://centmaster/input directory, I have 2 files:

file1.txt:

```
2012-3-1 a
2012-3-2 b
2012-3-3 c
2012-3-4 d
2012-3-5 a
2012-3-6 b
2012-3-7 c
2012-3-3 c
```

and file2.txt:

```
2012-3-1 b
2012-3-2 a
2012-3-3 b
2012-3-4 d
2012-3-5 a
2012-3-6 c
2012-3-7 d
2012-3-3 c
```

I run a Data Deduplication MapReduce code:

```
package Hadoop_for_jar;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class Dedup2 {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<Object,Text,Text,Text>{
        private static Text line=new Text();
        public void map(Object key,Text value,Context context)
                throws IOException,InterruptedException{
            line=value;
            context.write(line, new Text(""));
        }

    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>{
        public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> values,Context context)
                throws IOException,InterruptedException{
            context.write(key, new Text(""));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "root");
        String[] otherArgs = {"hdfs://centmaster:9000/input", "hdfs://centmaster:9000/output/debup1"};
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Data Deduplication");
        job.setJarByClass(Dedup.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
     }
}
```

It runs successfully. The result is:

```
2012-3-1 a
2012-3-1 b
2012-3-2 a
2012-3-2 b
2012-3-3 b
2012-3-3 c
2012-3-4 d
2012-3-5 a
2012-3-6 b
2012-3-6 c
2012-3-7 c
2012-3-7 d
```

Now, I'm thinking, that Reducer doesn't use the Value of input (Key, Value) of Reducer, which is the output of Mapper.

It is useless for this program. I want to change the Text into IntWritable, and I hope it will get the same result. So, I

made the following change:

```
package Hadoop_for_jar;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class Dedup2 {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<Object,Text,Text,IntWritable>{   //Change Text to IntWritable
        private static Text line=new Text();
        public void map(Object key,Text value,Context context)
                throws IOException,InterruptedException{
            line=value;
            context.write(line, new IntWritable(0));    //Change Text("") to IntWritable(0)
        }

    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,Text>{ //Change Text to IntWritable
        public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context)   //Change Text to IntWritable
                throws IOException,InterruptedException{
            context.write(key, new Text(""));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "root");
        String[] otherArgs = {"hdfs://centmaster:9000/input", "hdfs://centmaster:9000/output/debup2"};
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Data Deduplication");
        job.setJarByClass(Dedup2.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
     }
}
```

And there is the /output/debup2 directory. But the directory is empty. My assumption is wrong. So, my question is that: does Reducer() only accept (Text, Text) for input?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. According to the below link, the output of Mapper and Reducer should be the same. If you want to set different output of Mapper and Reducer, the Combiner should be avoided.

[Error: java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text is not class Myclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377011/error-java-io-ioexception-wrong-value-class-class-org-apache-hadoop-io-text-i)